# regular expression to delete all words after the first

Tags: regex, vim

in a text file, for every line, delete the charaters begin from a space to the
end of the line.

for example: in the file which has two lines:

```
hello world
foo  good good
```

after handling, the file would look like

```
hello    
foo
```

I have tried `^\+\s`, but it seems only deal with the spaces at the end of the line

Answer (score 7):

Don't you just want

```
:%s/\s.*//
```

Where it matches everything after and including the first space. Then removes whats matched.

Comment: The two `//` at the end are optionnal.

Answer (score 3):

For good measure, a simple solution that doesn't involve regular expressions (or much thinking, actually):

```
:%norm f D
```

Explanation:

- `:{range}normal {command}` executes normal mode `{command}` on the line(s) specified by `{range}`.
- Used as a range, `%` means "every line in the current buffer".
- `f<space>` is an horizontal motion, it jumps on the next `<space>` on the line.
- `D` deletes everything from the cursor to the end of the line.

Regular expressions are fascinating but it can take too much time to come up with the right regular expression pattern when normal mode commands could do the job in a more intuitive manner.

Comment: it works and is cool, could you explain a litte bit about this ?